# Why Openiddict automatically validate client_id?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I want to generate a token with four parameter client_id,client_secret, username & user password. Client_Id & client_secret are optional requirement. When I generate token with username & user password its working fine but when i try to  pass client_id, it fails with 500 internal server error.

When i check the log and found:

### No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

### My Service Configuration

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict()
            // Register the OpenIddict core services.
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<DbContext>();
            })
          
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.UseMvc();
                options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
                options.AllowPasswordFlow().AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
                options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
                options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(4));
                options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
                options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
               
            })
            .AddValidation();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
    }
```

### LOG

```
  fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HLJJPK2L74A1", Request id "0HLJJPK2L74A1:00000003": An 
  unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been 
  configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by 
  overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext 
  on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also 
  ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> 
  object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for 
  DbContext.

 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
  at 
  OpenIddict.Core.OpenIddictApplicationManager`1.FindByClientIdAsync(String 
  identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at OpenIddict.Core.OpenIddictApplicationManager`1. 
  OpenIddict.Abstractions.IOpenIddictApplicationManager. 
  FindByClientIdAsync(String identifier, CancellationToken 
  cancellationToken)
```

Problem is this only happen when i pass client_id on token request. I think this client_Id is automatically validate by openiddict. I want to validate this client_id on my '/connect/token' method.

I don't configure any dbcontext in my application. Is there any way
to generate token with client_id & client_secret & user id & user Pass without configure below line or is there any other configuration to do that

```
  .AddCore(options =>
            {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<DbContext>();
            })
```

I am using oracle database for my application.

Answer (score 0):

> Client_Id & client_secret are optional requirement.

They are: a public client can indeed avoid sending its client identifier, as allowed by the OAuth2 specification. If you've configured OpenIddict to disable the client identification requirement (enforced by default), the request will be considered valid if the `client_id` is not present.

That said, if you specify a `client_id`, then it MUST correspond to a real application. OpenIddict validates that by asking the underlying store (EF Core in your case) if an application with the specified `client_id` exists. If the DB provider is not correctly configured, you'll get an exception like the one you're seing.

OpenIddict was not designed to be used without a backing DB (to store applications, authorizations or tokens).

If you prefer an (almost) stateless experience, you may want to give ASOS - the low-level OIDC server handler behind OpenIddict - a try: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server. It will support your scenario without forcing you to create a DB.

Comment: and a public client in OpenIddict will have [a type of "public" and a null or empty client secret](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/db9b5493f982c3198d9a2df781685a3ce3624b74/src/OpenIddict.Core/Managers/OpenIddictApplicationManager.cs#L1192)